# How to remove unnecessary whitespace before \begin{enumerate}?

Tags: formatting, vertical-alignment, enumerate, itemize

I've defined a new environment via

```
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{aufg}{Exercise}
\newenvironment{problem}[1]{\begin{aufg}[#1] ~ \\*[0.2em]}{\end{aufg}}
```

Then writing

```
\begin{problem}{Maximizing a profit function}
        A firm produces two output goods, denoted by $A$ and $B$.
        The cost per day is [...]
```

yields a nice gap between header and body of the exercise:

[image]

But I am running into issues, if the exercise starts with enumerating straight away. E.g.

```
\begin{problem}{Envelope result}
        \begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*), topsep=-1000pt]
            \item Suppose the production function of Example 3.5 from the lecture is [...]
```

yields

[image]

How can I make this gap before enumerating smaller?

I've already tried the `topsep` config, but it didn't help much.

Comment: Look at the enumitem package

Comment: I am using enumit, hence the attempt with the topsep option. Didn't help me so far though. Anything particular to look at?

Comment: you need to edit parksip as well: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXqHq.png

Comment: Didn't help me. It seems enumitem allows me no more than moving up the enumeration by more than topsep=-\parskip. Additional parameters like parskip={0pt}, partopsep={0pt} or even negative values don't help.

Comment: Please provide complete small document, which reproduce your problem. Fro9m your code fragments we cant see, what you doing (hoe you use `enumitem`, if you really use it).

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround is to use \vspace.

```
\begin{problem}{Envelope result}
     \vspace{-0.2cm}\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*), topsep=-1000pt]
            \item Suppose the production function of Example 3.5 from the lecture is [...]
```